# Rails 4 SQL genereted by console is different of executed by action

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-console

I tried to create a job with search of results using a text field containing a date (YYYY-MM-DD), where it should bring me only 1 result for each month.

**For example:**
If they have two or more records with dates of the same month, even if they are different days, only the first record of the month must be returned.

The problem is when I run the command on the console, it runs my query exactly as it should, when it executes via an action Rails generates a different SQL.

**I already tried this:**

1) `Model.select("DISTINCT DATE_FORMAT(date_column, '%Y-%m') as date").where(id: model_id)`

2) `Model.select("DATE_FORMAT(date_column, '%Y-%m') as date").where(id: model_id).distinct`

**Console query:**

1 and 2 return same query
`SELECT DISTINCT DATE_FORMAT(date_column, '%Y-%m') as date FROM model WHERE model.id = 1`

**Action query:**

1) `SELECT COUNT (*) FROM model WHERE model.id = 1`

2) `SELEC DISTINC id FROM model WHERE model.id = 1`

What am I doing wrong or how could I do this search correctly?

**I use:**

Rails 4
MariaDB
Unicorn
Irb